# Где ошибка или как открыть все файлы?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$arrDir = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/111/');

foreach($arrDir as $element) { #Перебираем файлы

  if(preg_match('/.dat/',$element)) 
  { 
$_m = fopen('$element', "r");

$m1 = fread($_m, filesize("$element"));

$m2 = explode(".", $m1);

echo "$m2[0]<br/>";
```

Подскажите, где ошибка или как открыть все файлы?

**Обновление**

Код вроде правильный, если взять

```
[php]$_m = fopen('1.dat', "r");

$m1 = fread($_m, filesize("1.dat"));

$m2 = explode(".", $m1);

echo "$m2[0]<br/>";

echo "$m2[1]<br/>"; [/php]
```

// то выводит первые 2-е данные, что мне нужны. Но с одного файла, а мне нужно, чтобы он вытаскивал со всех в данной папке.

---

`preg_match('/\.dat$/'`  // не решило проблему, данные не извлекаются из файлов.

Код вроде правильный, если взять

```
[php]$_m = fopen('1.dat', "r");

$m1 = fread($_m, filesize("1.dat"));

$m2 = explode(".", $m1);

echo "$m2[0]<br/>";

echo "$m2[1]<br/>"; [/php]
```

// то выводит первые 2-е данные, что мне нужны. Но с одного файла, а мне нужно, чтобы он вытаскивал со всех в данной папке.

---

`preg_match('/\.dat$/'`  // не решило проблему, данные не извлекаются из файлов.

Answer (score 1):

1)

```
preg_match('/\.dat$/'
```

\. чтобы выбирались не все символы, а именно точка
$ чтобы на .dat файл ЗАКАНЧИВАЛСЯ

2) не закрыта фигурная скобка у if

Это как минимум. Обычно такие ошибки у тех, кто не использует нормальную IDEшку.

**Обновление**

IDE - это среда разработки. При программировании в блокноте или даже в блокноте с подсветкой синтаксиса, вы лишаетесь помощи в вещах, в которых компьютер гарантированно работает быстрее вас: проверка скобок, типов данных, названий.

По сути, код вполне верным задумывался, хотя и не идеален. Попробуйте внести правки, потом написать что получилось, какие входные данные и что ожидалось получить, если ответ полностью не исправит проблему.

**Обновление**

Данные вытаскивайте `file_get_contents($filename);`. С ней мороки меньше, хотя и есть недостатки.

Comment: Нормальную IDEшку? Поподробнее, есть альтернатива, как можно открывать файлы и проводить с ними операции?

Comment: if(preg_match('/\.dat$/',$element))

  { 

   $homepage = file_get_contents('$element');

так разве нельзя делать?

Comment: Нельзя. Кавычки уберите, иначе переменная не распарсится.

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents($element): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Comment: @romaaa32 - Вам же пишут английским по белому - "не могу найти папку или файл". Значит путь не верный указываете в переменной.